# Devexpress in .net c# mvc after click of export to pdf i want to call a user defined method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

**In .net MVC I am using devExpress for report generating but I am facing a problem  and that is, there an option to export to pdf on that I want to add some functionality, so how can i override or call a method after that method execute.**

> below I am showing the image on which after clicking on pdf it will execute my code also,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfSpS.png)

Comment: Which kind of functionality should be added to the PDF export? There are overloads available with [`ExportToPdf`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport.ExportToPdf.overloads) method, you can set `PdfExportOptions` argument there.